# Can we initialize two arrays in two different qubits in a 2-qubit quantum circuit in IBMq?

Tags: quantum-gate

Can we initialize two different arrays in two different qubits in a 2 qubit quantum circuit?
I tried in IBMq but it showing error.
So don't understand.

[image]

from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
num_of_qubits = 2
q1,q2 = QuantumRegister(1, 'q1'),QuantumRegister(1, 'q2')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
qc = QuantumCircuit(q1,q2,creg_c)
qc.initialize(message_chunks,q1)
qc.initialize(key_chunks,q2)

tried with this. but this error is showing.."'Desired statevector length not a positive power of 2.'"
kindly help..

Comment: It should work. Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: I added the SS above. It is not running. Waited for a long time but no response.

Comment: and after some time showing "The kernel for Untitled6.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Answer (score 0):

You code converts the content an image file into sequence of zeros and ones then for each bit inserts `Initialize` instruction in the quantum circuit. That means even for a small image you will insert thousands of `Initialize` instructions.  Most probably this is the root cause of the issue. You can easily check this by limiting the number of `Initialize` instructions by replacing this line:

```
for x in range(len(message_chunks)):
```

by

```
for x in range(20):
```

Note: you insert all these instructions to the same qubit. Are you sure this is what you are trying to do? because `Initialize` resets the value of the qubit before adding the gates needed to prepare the state. So, it is seems pointless to add a sequence of `Initialize` instructions to the same qubit without any processing after each instruction.

Comment: i understand mam.. else how i do i insert the message chuck and key chuck in the qubits? by which method?

Comment: I will use another operator after this and will measure it. but how to insert?

Comment: I think you need to know more about how to represent and input data into a quantum computer. [This link](https://github.com/Qiskit/platypus/blob/main/notebooks/v2/quantum-machine-learning/encoding.ipynb) can be a good starting point.